# windows audio waveOutSetVolume cross connects midiOutSetVolume

Tags: windows, audio

i have a program that generates both midi and wav audio. i need to be able to control the volume and balance of midi and audio separately and in theory, its seems like all i need to do is call

```
  unsigned short left = (unsigned short)(wavvol*wavbal/100.0);
  unsigned short right = (unsigned short)(wavvol*(100-wavbal)/100.0);
  MMRESULT err = waveOutSetVolume(hWaveOut, left | (right<<16)); // for audio
```

and

```
  unsigned short left = (unsigned short)(midivol*midibal/100.0);
  unsigned short right = (unsigned short)(midivol*(100-midibal)/100.0);
  MMRESULT err = midiOutSetVolume(s_hmidiout, left | (right<<16)); // for midi
```

for midi

the problem it, controlling midi volume sets wave volume and visa-verse, its like they are glues together inside windows

does anyone know if there is a way to unglue them?

BTW, i'm on windows 7, i know Microsoft messed up audio in win7. on XP i had an audio control panel with separate controls for midi and wave, that seems to have gone. i guess they just mix it down internally now and don't expose that even at the API level so maybe i've answered my own question.

still interested to know if there is a better answer through.

thanks, steve

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they can be separated. You could move to the newer [IAudioClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface and use two [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679162.aspx) sessions to control the volume separately - one for wav and one for midi. This won't work on anything below Vista tho.

Alternatively you could track the volume levels in-code and as long as you don't play back both wav and midi at the same time reset them before playback.